# How to Merge two Columns Data in one Column in c#

Tags: c#, xml, windows, xlsx, xmltextwriter

I am making a xlsx to xml convertor windows form app in c# i am getting a input ".xlsx" file and exporting a ".xml" file using "XmlTextWriter" method.I want to merge my two columns of Excel Sheet Named as "Date" and "Time" in One Column of "Date and Time" how i can do that? please help as i am new to c#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace XLSXtoXMLConvertor
{
public partial class XLSXtoXMLConvertor : Form
{
    public XLSXtoXMLConvertor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Load_Excel_File(textBox1.Text);

    }
    public void Load_Excel_File(string file)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(file) || !File.Exists(file))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The Excel file is invalid / No FIle Selected! Please select a valid file.");
            return;
        }

        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        Excel.Range range;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(file, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;


        //Map_Table = new DataTable();

        for (int j = 1; j <= range.Columns.Count; j++) // Header Names
        {
            xlWorkSheet.Range["H1"].Value2 = "Fueling Station";
            xlWorkSheet.Range["C1"].Value2 = "Comments";
            xlWorkSheet.Range["D1"].Value2 = "Current Odometer Reading";
            xlWorkSheet.Range["M1"].Value2 = "Vehicle Number";
            xlWorkSheet.Range["N1"].Value2 = "Quantity";
            xlWorkSheet.Range["O1"].Value2 = "Cost per Gallon";
            xlWorkSheet.Range["P1"].Value2 = "Total Cost";
            xlWorkSheet.Range["F1"].Value2 = "Date";
            xlWorkSheet.Range["G1"].Value2 = "Time";
            // Use if want to get column headers.
        }

        //DataRow dataRow = null;
                XmlTextWriter txtWriter = null;  
                string test = "C:\\Users\\muhammad.irfan\\Desktop\\" + "Mileage and Fuel Usage.xml";//save xml file 
                txtWriter = new XmlTextWriter(test, null); 
                //string FileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();
                //XmlTextWriter txtWriter = new XmlTextWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName, Encoding.UTF8);
                //txtWriter.WriteStartDocument(true);

                //StringWriter s = new StringWriter();
                //txtWriter = XmlWriter.Create(s);

                //try
                //{
                txtWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                txtWriter.Indentation = 6;
                txtWriter.Namespaces = false;

                txtWriter.WriteStartDocument();
                txtWriter.WriteStartElement("", "Root", ""); // start Tag
                txtWriter.WriteStartElement("", "Tag", ""); // Inside

                // for (int row = 1; row < range.Rows.Count + 1; row++)
                for (int row = 1; row < range.Rows.Count; row++)
                {
                    // for (int col = 1; col <= range.Columns.Count; col++)
                    for (int col = 1; col <= range.Columns.Count; col++)
                    {
                        if ((col.Equals(1) || (col.Equals(2) || (col.Equals(5) || (col.Equals(9) || (col.Equals(10) || (col.Equals(11) || (col.Equals(12) || (col.Equals(17) || (col.Equals(18)))))))))))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        string test1 = (string)(range.Cells[row, col] as Excel.Range).Text.ToString();
                        if (test1 != null)
                     // richTextBox1((range.Cells[row, col] as Excel.Range).Text.ToString());
                      //richTextBox1.AppendText((range.Cells[row, col] as Excel.Range).Text.ToString());
                        txtWriter.WriteStartElement(((range.Cells[col] as Excel.Range).Text.ToString()));
                        txtWriter.WriteString(((range.Cells[row, col] as Excel.Range).Text.ToString()));
                        txtWriter.WriteEndElement();
                    }
                }

                txtWriter.WriteEndElement();  // end Tag
                txtWriter.WriteEndElement(); // end Inside
                txtWriter.Flush();
                txtWriter.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Converted Successfully!");
                try
                {
                    xlWorkBook.Close(false, null, null);
                    xlApp.Quit();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {


                    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
                    releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
                    releaseObject(xlApp);
                }          
    }

    private void releaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
            obj = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            obj = null;

        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Initializes a OpenFileDialog instance 
        using (OpenFileDialog openfileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            openfileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
            openfileDialog.Filter = "Excel files(*.xlsx;*.xls)|*.xlsx;*.xls";

            if (openfileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = openfileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //using (SaveFileDialog savefiledialog = new SaveFileDialog())
        //{
        //    savefiledialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
        //    savefiledialog.DefaultExt = "xml";
        //    savefiledialog.Filter = "All Files(*.xml)|*.xml";
        //    if (savefiledialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        //    {
        //        /*
        //         Stream filestream = savefiledialog.OpenFile();
        //         StreamWriter streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream);
        //         streamwriter.Write("<?xml version='1.0'?>" +
        //         Environment.NewLine + textBox1.Text.ToString());
        //         streamwriter.Close();*/


        //    }
        //} 




   }

    private void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have so far.

Comment: I have posted whole code as answer. see and please help

Comment: I have edited your code into your question. It shouldn't be posted as an answer.

Comment: is the xlsx file always laid out the same?

Comment: Yes it will be same always